# Is there any writef() format specifier for a bool?

Tags: chapel

I looked at the **`writef()`** documentation for any **`bool`** specifier and there didn't seem to be any.

In a Chapel program I have:
...

```
config const verify = false;
/* that works but I want to use writef() to also print a bunch of other stuff*/
writeln("verify = " + verify); 
writef("verify = %<what-specifier-goes-here>\n", verify);
```

This last statement works ok.

```
// I guess I could do:

writef( "verify = %s\n",if verify then "true" else "false");
```

Comment: I thought that this was a reasonable feature request, so filed a GitHub issue against Chapel for it: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#about-io-formatted-io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [`FormattedIO` documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html), there is not a **`bool`** specifier available in Chapel's formatted IO.

Instead, you can use the generic specifier (`%t`) to print **`bool`** types in formatted IO:

```
config const verify = false;
writef("verify = %t\n", verify);
```

This specifier utilizes the `writeThis` or `readWriteThis` method of the type to print the variable. The [Chapel IO documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelIO.html#the-readthis-writethis-and-readwritethis-methods) provides more details on how these methods work.

Comment: With all due respect Ben, what was **any rational reason to roll back** the improvement edits -- one corrected typo and added a more accurate explanation about the Chapel actually not having any `writef(...)`-formatting specifier for `bool`-eans, but having a possibility to use a smart-trick with a delegation of the `FormattedIO` presentation of a `bool`-hard-typed value ( brought in by the `verify` constant ) onto its own type-inherrited `writeThis()` routine? **Any missed reason? Ref. >>>** https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47243896/2

Comment: Hey - sorry, I wish you could document rollbacks the same way you can document edits. I think the extra detail was good, but did not agree with the other minor edits.

Comment: Not clear **which exact part** ( if any at all ) **of the "minor edits"** as you call it, have deserved your particular feeling that you cannot agree with their respective meaning so strong, that you have initiated a roll-back. **Be rather specific and exact + argument why --** no exceptions, no excuse in this -- otherwise there still seems no rational reason for a roll-back. ( Btw -- as per your wish -- *anyone can document* calling a roll-back Ref. >>> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47243896/revisions )

Comment: Apologies if I've broken SO etiquette by rolling back your edit. I've reincorporated the edits that I agreed with. Hopefully this is more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

### No, there is no such `<specifier>` for bool in **`FormattedIO`**

As [**documentation** explains,](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html?highlight=writef#overview-of-format-strings) there is no such `bool`-value specific specifier in the recent Chapel language release.

A **`verify`** value-based conversion is fine.

```
config const verify    =  false;
var aTrueFalseAsSTRING = "false";

if verify then aTrueFalseAsSTRING = "true";

writef( "verify = %s\n",
         aTrueFalseAsSTRING
         );
```